# How to run tensorflow model twice before computing the loss

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I want to compute a loss function which uses output of the network twice on different inputs. For example as hypothetically,

```
first_output = model(first_input)
second_output = model(second_input)
loss = mean_absolute_error(first_output, second_output)
```

How to achieve this in tensorflow or keras?

Comment: Why not putting both inputs in batch? So with one run, your model will predict on both inputs. And you will have both outputs and could use them for loss calculation.

Comment: Yes that is possible. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

So, as in comment:

Put as many inputs in the batch as you want, and the run prediction on that batch. That way, you could use all outputs to calculate the loss function.

### Keras

In Keras framework, if you want to calculate the `mean_absolute_error` as you state in your question, you could use predefined [mean_absolute_error](https://keras.io/losses/#mean_absolute_error) loss. Also, to have two inputs as you state in your question, specify the batch size of the model to 2.